# Express Route not being found

Tags: javascript, express

I have 3 routes currently, see here:

```
app.get('/', require("./routes/home"));
app.use('/blog', require("./routes/blog"));
app.get('/projects', require("./routes/projects"));
```

blog and home are just fine, projects however does not match and just says "Cannot GET".

I read a few stack overflow resources, google dev resources, etc with the same error but none of the solutions seem to be working.

Here is my `routes/projects` file as it stands:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
  //database query for all projects to be passed to the view
  res.render("projects", {
    pageTitle: "Projects",
    projects: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "project 1"
    }]
  });
});

router.get("/project/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  //database query for a specific project based on the id
  //res.render('project-info', { pageTitle, projectName, projectDetail });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the views/projects.jsx file it is rendering (or atleast should):

```
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = require('./layouts/default');
var projectCard = require("./components/project-card.jsx");

class projectInfo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var projects = this.props.projects.map(function(project, i) {
      return <projectCard id={project.id} projectName={project.name} />;
    });

    return (<DefaultLayout pageTitle={`James Robb Web Developer | ${this.props.pageTitle}`}>
      {projects}
    </DefaultLayout>);
  }
}

module.exports = projectInfo;
```

Am I missing something here? Because nothing seems to be working to fix the issue and I need the route to work obviously.

If you have any questions, please just ask!

To clarify, I am using express-react-views, that is why I am rendering a .jsx react file for my page, instead of pug or hogan for example, it works fine on the other pages... just incase someone things that is the issue, it isnt.

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Just 404 not found. thats it.

Comment: What would happen if you simply put `res.json({ success: true });` inside of your `/` route? Does it return the expected JSON?

Comment: also, in `projects.jsx`, shouldn't this: `{\`James Robb Web Developer | ${this.props.pageTitle}\`}` be this: `{\`James Robb Web Developer || ${this.props.pageTitle}\`}`

Comment: Was there any luck with this?

Comment: It is a template string, so the || isnt an OR operator, it is literally just a pipe.

Comment: And I tried the res.json idea but it still just says "cannot GET /projects"

Comment: Very confusing issue as all the other routes are found, rendered, etc in the exact same way and work..

Comment: Fixed it!!! had to change app.get to app.use.. I dont understand this since app.get("/") works... but ok. Problem sorted now.